# How to custom operations in the forward function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, image

I am doing an experiment on images of small size as follows:

The input image has only one channel, then I apply 2 customed filters (denoted by A and B) to do the convolution with the image. The filter has the same size as the image and each of A and B have 10 channels respectively. So after the convolution we have two 1 * 10 tensors. Denote them as (a1, a2, ... a10) and (b1, b2, ... b10). Let w = (w1, w2, ..., w10) be a trainable 1 *10 tensor. Then I want to compute the following fraction: (the numerator is the norm of weighted sum of vectors (ai, bi) and the denominator is the sum of weighted norm. The norm here is the ordinary Euclidean norm.)
[image]
I am wondering how to do this computation in the forward function and where I should claim w as trainable tensor? The template of my code is as follows:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.filter_A = ...
        self.filter_B = ...

    def forward(self, x):
        x_A = F.conv2d(x, self.filter_A)
        x_B = F.conv2d(x, self.filter_B)
        ...
```